# JQUERY Login Page

Tags: php, jquery, html

problem is that this button is not working. it never go to javascript function.i have also tried using $('#Btnlogin').on('click', function(){.. but still not working

jquery Function

```
   $(document).on('click', '#Btnlogin', function(){
   var email = $('#mailselect').val();
   var pass = $('#password').val();
   if(email != '' && pass != '')
   {
    $.ajax({
     url:"Login-execute.php",
     method:"POST",
     data:{email:email, pass:pass},
     success:function(data)
     {
     if(data == 'A'){
     window.location.href = "admin/index.php";
     }
     else if(data == 'U'){
     window.location.href = "Login-home.php";
     }
      else if(data == 'SS'){
     window.location.href = "login.php";
     }
     else(
      $('#message').html('<span class="alert-success">'+data+'</span>');
      $("#clearfrm")[0].reset();
      }
     }
    });
    setInterval(function(){
     $('#message').html('');
    }, 5000);
   }
   else
   {
    alert("All Fields are required");
   }
  });
```

html code

```
<form id="clearfrm" >
<input name="email" type="email" id="mailselect" class="form-control"   required autocomplete="off">
<input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control"  required autocomplete="off">
<button type="button" name="btnsub" id="Btnlogin">Sign In</button>                  
</form>
```

Comment: You are expecting the php code, which is called via ajax, to redirect to another page? Not going to happen. Ajax returns the text/html source of any page that php returns. PHP should return logged in true or false and jquery should do the redirection if log in is true.

Comment: JQuery will not take you to the header location URL. You have to use `window.location` or other javascript methods to redirect the browser based on response that is received by JQuery.

Comment: <form id="clearfrm"><input name="email" type="email" id="mailselect" class="form-control"   required autocomplete="off"><input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control"  required autocomplete="off"><button type="button" name="btnsub" id="Btnlogin">Sign In </button></form>............$(document).on('click', '#Btnlogin', function(){SOME CODE  }); MY problem is that the button is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the Header from PHP to redirect. This only works on context of the script being executed directly from the browser, not through an ajax request.
Pass it over back to the jQuery ajax and call the redirect from there as such:

#### jQuery

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Login-execute.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {email.email, pass:pass},
    success: function (data) { 
        window.location.href = data;
    },
    contentType: 'text/plain'
});
```

#### PHP

```
if ($count == 1) {
    $member = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $type = $member['type'];
    if ($type == 'admin') {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['myemail'] = $member['email'];
        $_SESSION['mypassword'] = $member['passwrd'];
        echo 'admin/index.php'; // Output location instead of header
        exit();
    } elseif ($type == 'user') {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['myemail'] = $member['email'];
        $_SESSION['mypassword'] = $member['passwrd'];
        echo 'Login-home.php'; // Same here, instead of header
        exit();
    }
}
```

Another note, on the topic of security, avoid storing/comparing your passwords as plaintext, this can lead to many problems in the case some data leaks as users tend to re-use passwords elsewhere.

Please look into upgrading (if you're not already doing so) to using the PHP built in `password_hash` function and `password_verify` to check for correct password. Read more on that [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Comment: <form id="clearfrm"><input name="email" type="email" id="mailselect" class="form-control"   required autocomplete="off"><input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control"  required autocomplete="off"><button type="button" name="btnsub" id="Btnlogin">Sign In </button></form>............$(document).on('click', '#Btnlogin', function(){SOME CODE  }); MY problem is that the button is not working

Comment: @sssst The jquery to trigger on click needs to select the button directly. Such as `$('#Btnlogin`).on('click', function() { ... })`.

Comment: @sssst correct, `$(document)` refers to the entire page, if you want an action on a button click, then you want to make sure it's only the button you're attaching it to.

Comment: $('#Btnlogin').on('click', function(){ this is how i have tried but still not triggering

Comment: @sssst suggest that you update the original answer with the full code you have now. However, look at your javascript console `Ctrl + Shift + I` in most browsers and check for any syntax errors or place a `console.log()` to view if you're getting to the trigger event.

Comment: i am editing my question. plz jst have a look. i will be thankful to you

Comment: @sssst Line 21 of your example has a bracket and not a brace causing a syntax error.

Comment: why email is not validating. plz suggest something that just add email validation